# How to Generate Random Number Based on Probability in Java

Tags: java, sampling

I want to randomly select a '1' 10% of the time, a '2' 30% of the time and a '3' the other 60% of a time. I am wondering if there is a method that allows me to randomly sample based on these probabilities in Java.

Thank you

Comment: **"Random number based on probability"** --- Isn't that what random numbers are anyway (without getting too technical)?

Comment: you could generate a random number between 1 and 100. Then if the result is 1-10 return 1, if the result is between 10-40 return 2, and if the result is greater than 40 return 3.

Comment: use an array `{ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 }` or a list, shuffle and pick one

Comment: The random Int generator in Java randomly selects a int with every integer within a range to have equal probability to be selected. I want to alter that probability of being selected to 10% 30% and 60%. I know there is a function to do this in R. But I can't find that in Java. I am enquiring if anyone knows of a method.

Comment: Do what the guys above said, and use a random number between 1 and 100 to determine which one to pick.

Comment: I had thought of that bhspencer I was just wondering if there was a method that already existed?

Comment: use a random generator (int)(Math.random() * 100) +1) and then follow what they have said above.

Comment: Why not use the [commons.math object](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/EnumeratedDistribution.html) specifically designed for this?

Answer (score 9):

First generate a double that's uniformly distributed between 0.0 and 1.0. Then split the range (0.0 < x < 1.0) into subranges that correspond to your desired probabilities:

- 0.0 <= x < 0.1 becomes 1 (interval width is (0.1 - 0.0) = 0.1, or 10%);
- 0.1 <= x < 0.4 becomes 2 (interval width is (0.4 - 0.1) = 0.3, or 30%);
- 0.4 <= x < 1.0 becomes 3 (interval width is (1.0 - 0.4) = 0.6, or 60%).

In code:

```
double rand = rng.nextDouble();
if (rand < .1) {
  return 1;
} else if (rand < .1 + .3) {
  return 2;
} else {
  return 3;
}
```

(where `rng` is an instance of `java.util.Random`.)

This method can be easily generalised to an arbitrary set of target probabilities.

Comment: You meant `.3` for *"30% of the time"*, for a calculated value of `.1 + .3 = .4`, leaving a `.6` range up to `1.0` for the last *"60% of a time"*.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is applicable in every language. Just get a big random number, then take a mod of some number, and check for ranges.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(10000000);
int m = r % 10;
if (m < 1) return 1; // 10 %
else if (m < 4) return 2; // 30 %
else return 3; // 60 %
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no method in the standard in the Java API. You can write your own algorithm, you can try using [MockNeat.probabilities()](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat/wiki/MockNeat#probabilities) method that is doing exactly what you ask.

For example:

```
String s = mockNeat.probabilites(String.class)
                .add(0.1, "A") // 10% chance to pick "A"
                .add(0.2, "B") // 20% chance to pick "B"
                .add(0.5, "C") // 50% chance to pick "C"
                .add(0.2, "D") // 20% chance to pick "D"
                .val();
```

*Disclaimer: I am the author of the library, so I might be biased when I am recommending it.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think theres a method for that, you would just have to perform a workaround like the following

Generate a random number from 1-10 inclusive, and then select 1,2 or 3 depending on the probability of the random chance.

```
if (random_number == 1)
{
  result = 1;
}
else if (random_number <= 4)
{
  result = 2;
}
else
{
result = 3;
}
```

Comment: There is a method. `nextDouble` will return a uniformly distributed number between 0 and 1.0. You can then use that to make the selection.